# Can't get Firefox to start

Tags: 10.04, firefox

My firefox has had all sorts of trauma.

- the addition of the firefox-daily ppa and also version 4 from the same PPA. I since removed this and now have version `3.6.9+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1`
- removal of firefox profile folder and general playing with different profiles

But now I can't get it to do anything, not even startup. All the following produce nothing:

```
$ firefox
$ firefox -safe-mode
$ firefox -private
$ firefox -ProfileManager
```

Strangely (or not) `firefox --help` and `firefox -version` behave as anticipated. Anyone got any suggestions as to how to resurrect my firefox?

Comment: Have you checked if there are any running Firefox processes, using `ps ax | grep -i firefox` for example? If there are, try killing them off with `kill <pid>` or `kill -9 <pid>` before starting a new one.

Comment: @Lars No joy I'm afraid. (Unsurprisingly as the issue persists after restarting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I had a broken symlink at `/home/greg/.mozilla` after I deleted the the firefox profile from my files area, but didn't remove the symlink.

Comment: Thanks, removing /home/USER/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

First activate the backports repository to make ppa-purge available. Then:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
ppa-purge firefox-daily
sudo apt-get purge firefox
mv /home/user.name/.mozilla/firefox /home/user.name/.mozilla/firefox.bak
sudo apt-get reinstall xulrunner-1.9.2
sudo apt-get install firefox-gnome-support firefox-branding
```

Comment: It felt promising as I watched the console lines scroll by, but didn't work. (I even restarted to check, just in case)

Comment: What if you delete your profile after purging firefox?

Comment: I have added an option to reinstall xulrunner. It's quite frustrating the lack of debug info that firefox outputs :(.

Comment: Figured it out (see my answer), thanks for the help though.